# PDF.JS - How to store PDF on server

Tags: javascript, pdf, pdf.js

I am new to pdf.js.  I am able to view PDFs using the example viewer and all is good.  I'm able to view an interactive Acroform and fill out the fields too.  When I view the Acroform, the "download" button mysteriously disappears.  I type some data into a text field on my PDF form.  Now, I would like to upload the PDF (with the data in the text field) to a server side servlet.  To simulate, I tried to download but, remember?  The button is missing!  So, I open the dev tools in chrome and unhide the download button and click it.  Viola!  It downloads the PDF to my local drive (with the data in the text field).

Now, instead of going to my local drive, I was to POST this to a servlet and save it server-side.

Any clues or hints would be greatly appreciated . . .